# How can I install Lib::XML on ActiveState Perl 5.20?

Tags: windows, perl, activeperl

I am trying to install Lib::XML in my ActiveState Perl Windows machine.

> perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2)

I tried the following:

```
C:\Users\VENKATESH>ppm install XML-LibXML
ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides XML-LibXML

C:\Users\VENKATESH>ppm install http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/XML-LibXML.ppd
ppm install failed: 500 Can't connect to theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca:80
```

How do I install packages for Perl on Windows?

Comment: ActiveState's ppm repo [doesn't have it](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/XML-LibXML/) for newer versions of Perl. So unless you know of another repository, you'll need to compile libxml2 and then use `cpan XML::LibXML`.

Comment: Please copy and paste error text into your questions instead of using screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) mentioned, XML-LibXML is available upto perl 5.16 and not later.

> [ppm install XML-LibXML](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/XML-LibXML/)

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, there doesn't seem to be a pre-compiled PPM for ActiveState Perl 5.20.  I contributed [instructions for building XML::LibXML from source on Windows](https://metacpan.org/source/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0120/README#L126).  Look for them in the [README](https://metacpan.org/source/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0120/README) file that comes with the distribution.  I haven't done it in a while, but I expect they still work.  I'll reproduce them here, but you should check the distribution for updates.

> These instructions assume that you already have your system set up to compile
>   modules that use C components.
>
> First, get the libxml2 binaries from http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/
>   (currently also available at http://www.zlatkovic.com/pub/libxml/).
>
> You need:
>
> ```
> iconv-VERSION.win32.zip
> libxml2-VERSION.win32.zip
> zlib-VERSION.win32.zip
> ```
>
> Download the latest version of each. (Each package will probably have a
>   different version.) When you extract them, you'll get directories named
>   iconv-*VERSION*.win32, libxml2-*VERSION*.win32, and zlib-*VERSION*.win32, each
>   containing bin, lib, and include directories.
>
> Combine all the bin, include, and lib directories under `c:\Prog\LibXML`. (You
>   can use any directory you prefer; just adjust the instructions accordingly.)
>
> Get the latest version of [XML-LibXML](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXML) from CPAN. Extract it.
>
> Issue these commands in the XML-LibXML-*VERSION* directory:
>
> ```
> perl Makefile.PL INC=-Ic:\Prog\LibXML\include LIBS=-Lc:\Prog\LibXML\lib
> nmake
> copy c:\Prog\LibXML\bin\*.dll blib\arch\auto\XML\LibXML
> nmake test
> nmake install
> ```
>
> (Note: Some systems use `dmake` instead of `nmake`.)
>
> By copying the `libxml2` DLLs to the `arch` directory, you help avoid conflicts
>   with other programs you may have installed that use other (possibly
>   incompatible) versions of those DLLs.

Comment: am using Win64bit .where can i find zip files for x64??

Comment: @VENKATESH, did you try the [64bit directory](http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/64bit/)? But it's the version of Perl that's most important.  You can install 32-bit Perl on Win64, in which case you'd want the 32-bit libxml.

Comment: > Get the latest version of XML-LibXML from CPAN. Extract it.  => I could not find any zip file or 7z file here

Comment: @VENKATESH, there isn't one.  You'll need to find a utility that can extract `.tar.gz` files.  I believe [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) will do it.

Comment: E:\work\perlWork\XML-LibXML-2.0121>perl Makefile.PL INC=-Ic:\Prog\LibXML\include
 LIBS=-Lc:\Prog\LibXML\lib
enable native perl UTF8
Checking for ability to link against xml2...no
Checking for ability to link against libxml2...libxml2, zlib, and/or the Math li
brary (-lm) have not been found.                                                         Try setting LIBS and INC values on the command line
Or get libxml2 from
  http://xmlsoft.org/
If you install via RPMs, make sure you also install the -devel
RPMs, as this is where the headers (.h files) are.

Comment: Also, you may try to run perl Makefile.PL with the DEBUG=1 parameter
to see the exact reason why the detection of libxml2 installation
failed or why Makefile.PL was not able to compile a test program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cpan` utility with ActiveState's Perl.

```
> cpan XML::LibXML
```

Comment: brary (-lm) have not been found.
Try setting LIBS and INC values on the command line
Or get libxml2 from
  http://xmlsoft.org/
If you install via RPMs, make sure you also install the -devel
RPMs, as this is where the headers (.h files) are.

Also, you may try to run perl Makefile.PL with the DEBUG=1 parameter
to see the exact reason why the detection of libxml2 installation
failed or why Makefile.PL was not able to compile a test program.
No 'Makefile' created  SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0119.tar.gz
  C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK

Comment: Try x86 version from ActiveState's site